# $L^1$ bound and derivative bound implies $L^p$ bound

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Suppose non-negative $f: [0, \infty)\to\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}$ is differentiable, with $f(0)=0$ and $f'\leqslant 1/2$. Show that if $\int_0^\infty f\,dx<\infty$, then for all $p>1$ we have
$$
\int_0^\infty f^p\,dx \leqslant \left(\int_0^\infty f\,dx\right)^{(p+1)/2}.
$$

Comment: $f'$ does not seem to appear in the inequality?

Comment: @Calvin Yeah. That seems strange.

Comment: Looks like a special case of an interpolation inequality for Sobolev spaces. Maybe you can take a look at the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality and take some inspiration from there.

Comment: @Ivb By Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality I can get $\int f^p\leq C\left(\int f\right)^{(p+1)/2}$, but how can I get rid of that constant $C$...

Comment: Did you mean $|f'|\le 1/2$?

Comment: @zhw No. Only the upper bound $f'\leq 1/2$ given.